# Docker environment variables in multi-stage builds

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

given this `.env` file:

```
TEST=33333
```

given this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  service_name:
    image: test
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      TEST: 22222
```

given this `Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM an_image AS builder

FROM another_image
ENV TEST 11111

CMD ["/bin/echo $TEST"]
```

Whenever I build and run this image in a container, it prints `11111`.

If I remove the `ENV 11111` line from the Dockerfile, my `TEST` environment variable is empty...

Is the parent image receiving the environment variables but not the child one?

Thanks!

EDIT:

1. trying `ENV TEST ${TEST}` didn't work ($TEST is empty)
2. removing `ENV TEST` didn't work ($TEST is empty)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So this is not a multi-stage issue.

It appears `ENV` variables are only used when running containers (`docker-compose up`). Not at build time (`docker-compose build`). So you have to use `arguments`:

**.env**:

```
TEST=11111
```

**docker-compose.yaml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        TEST: ${TEST}
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
ARG TEST
ENV TEST ${TEST}
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $TEST"]
```

**test command**:

```
docker rmi test_test:latest ; docker-compose build && docker run -it --rm test_test:latest
```

Seriously the documentation is somewhat lacking.

Reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1837

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue, are you really evaluating the variable in a `CMD`? The `CMD` is run time, not build time.

Comment: Is it possible to pass my .env file to the args?

Comment: ENV variables in a Dockerfile ARE actually available in both the build stage (i.e. RUN commands), and as environment variables in the running containers. See docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not about multi-stage specifically.

It's about differences between  Dockerfile `ARG` & docker-compose YAML `build` `args` ("build arguments"); and Dockerfile `ENV` & docker-compose YAML `environment`/`.env`.

[The docs were updated (more recently than the original post), and it is fairly clear now:](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args)

> #### `args`
>
> Add build arguments, which are environment variables accessible only during the build process.

#### Example from [the docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)

Starting simple, just showing the interaction between `Dockerfile` and the YAML:

```
ARG buildno
ARG gitcommithash

RUN echo "Build number: $buildno"
RUN echo "Based on commit: $gitcommithash"
```

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    buildno: 1
    gitcommithash: cdc3b19

build:
  context: .
  args:
    - buildno=1
    - gitcommithash=cdc3b19
```

#### Example to tie it back to the question:

See [the other answer in this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47176497)

---

## Docs & deepening your understanding

#### Learn one layer of abstraction at a time

I recommend to go from the Dockerfile level of abstraction, upward. Making sure you understand each layer before you add the next layer of abstraction.

1. Dockerfile (and then play with running containers from your Dockerfile ... using default `ENV`, then playing with `--env`, then playing with `ARG` and `--build-arg`)
2. Then add docker-compose details in, and play with those.
3. *Then* loop back to Dockerfiles and understanding multi-stage builds.

#### Dockerfile

A helpful blog-post -- focuses on the Dockerfile but in all cases, it's best to understand Dockerfiles alone before adding the extra layers of abstraction on top of that, such as docker-compose YAML.

https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/

[image: from vsupalov.com post about this subject, https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/]

#### docker-compose

Then docker-compose official docs:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file

#### multi-stage Dockerfiles

- https://docs.bitnami.com/containers/how-to/optimize-docker-images-multistage-builds/
- https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae
- https://github.com/garethr/multi-stage-build-example